# How to do minimum downtime migration using DMA?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

I'm using DMA to migrate sql server from source server to target server (on-prem).

After completing the migrate (for example it takes 1 hours and finishes at 2.30PM), meanwhile the source db is in use.

Prior to source db cutoff, how to transfer the subsequent data (that is not already in target server) from the source server dbs into the respective target server dbs?

Answer (score 2):

DMA (Database Migration Assistant) is probably the wrong tool for what you are trying to achieve. This is because the DB is brought back online (`WITH RECOVERY`) after the migration has been performed.

You would have to migrate the database with a BACKUP and RESTORE and once that has been done, apply any other additional TLOG backups.

#### Possible Solution

1. Backup Source Database at 10:00am

   ```
   BACKUP DATABASE [DB_NAME] TO DISK = 'S:\DIRECTORY\DB_NAME_FULL_20220411_100000.bak';
   ```
2. Restore to Target Database

   ```
   RESTORE DATABASE [DB_NAME] 
       FROM DISK = 'T:\DIRECTORY\DB_NAME_FULL_20220411_100000.bak'
       WITH INIT, 
       NO_RECOVERY; -- This being the important part.
   ```
3. Restore any additional TLOG Backups from source that occurred during the restore to target.

   ```
   RESTORE LOG [DB_NAME] 
       FROM DISK = 'T:\DIRECTORY\DB_NAME_TLOG_20220411_120000.bak' -- note the hour timestamp of TLOG backup
       WITH INIT, 
       NO_RECOVERY; -- This being the important part for the first TLOG restore
   RESTORE LOG [DB_NAME] 
       FROM DISK = 'T:\DIRECTORY\DB_NAME_TLOG_20220411_130000.bak' -- note the hour timestamp of TLOG backup
       WITH INIT, 
       NO_RECOVERY; -- This being the important part for the next TLOG restores
   ...
   RESTORE LOG [DB_NAME] 
       FROM DISK = 'T:\DIRECTORY\DB_NAME_TLOG_20220411_150000.bak'
       WITH INIT, 
       RECOVERY; -- This being the important part for the LAST TLOG restore
   ```

With the last TLOG restore your database is brought back ONLINE and fully functional.

<sup>***Reference:** [RESTORE Statements (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

---

#### Based on the additional questions asked in the comments here an extension to my initial answer.

*Yes indeed I have looked into the TLOG (and also differential backups) but they don't migrate sql server level logins, server roles, login-server role membership, login-securable permissions. Any recommendations for that please? Can you also mention about tail log backup in your answer - whether tail-log backup/restore is important?*

Perform your migration as a three step process:

1. Use DMA to "migrate" DB and Users/Logins.
2. Backup / Restore database.
3. Restore TLOGs

***Step 1 migrates the db; so step 2 is backup/restore of what please? Bit confused with this. Do you mean at step 2 I must delete the databases on the target, backup source db, restore on target?***

Yes. In order to have the tool assist you in migrating the users you have to do the "migration" twice. Once as a migration step and then again as a backup / restore which would allow you to further apply TLOG backups. There are possibly much more elegant ways to migrate a database with users/logins, but your question is about DMA and I'm building upon your initial question.

As for the **tail log backup**: Of course, this is the last step in your restore. Backup the TLOG of your source database one last time and then apply it your migrated database with the option `..., RECOVERY;`. The second last step would then have to have been a `..., NO_RECOVERY`.

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that - any changes/addition to server level login, roles, securable permissions will need to be re-applied. The database backups will auto sync the db level users, roles and securable permissions.